# PHP SELECT INSERT data(x) from table A to B, then prevent data(x) appear on SELECT table A

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 mySQL Tables:

```
A)`inventory` (`id`, `item`, `qty_left`, `qty_min`, `qty_max`, `cat_no`, `supplier`) VALUES
(1, 'Orange', 8, 10, 50, 1001, 'ACOMP'),
(2, 'Apple', 4, 10, 20, 1002, 'BCOMP'),
(3, 'Pear', 80, 20, 100, 1003, 'ACOMP'),
(4, 'Durian', 9, 60, 100, 1004, 'CCOMP');

B)`reorder_in_process` (`id`, `item`, `to_order`, `cat_no`, `supplier`, `time`) VALUES
(EMPTY);
```

I have PHP page: (purchaser.php)

```html
<!---------------Ajax Script To Confirm Purchase From Clicked Supplier------------>
<script>
  function tCat(value) {
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("reorder_in_process").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                      }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","purchaser_confirm_purchase.php?q="+value,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
           }
  </script>
  
<style>

#left_col {
 float: left;
 width: 33%;}
#mid_col {
 float: right;
 width: 33%;}
#reorder_in_process {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;}
#supplier {
 float: none;} 
</style>


<div id="left_Col">
<div>Items Need Reorder</div>
<?PHP
include ('db.php');
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM inventory  WHERE qty_left<=qty_min ORDER BY supplier ASC, item ASC");
$first_iteration = true;
$current_supplier = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$to_order = $row['qty_max']-$row['qty_left'];  
// If a new supplier is encountered, close the first table (if its no the first iteration) and add new header + start new table 
    if ($row['supplier'] != $current_supplier) {
        if ($first_iteration == false)
            echo "</table></div>";
        $i = 1;
        $first_iteration = false;
        $current_supplier = $row['supplier'];
        echo "<h4>".$row['supplier']."<button id='supplier' value=". $row['supplier']." onClick='tCat(value)'>Reorder Now</button></h4>";
        echo  "<div><table><tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Cat. No</th>                                            
                    <th>Buy QTY</th>
                    <th>Supplier</th>                   
                </tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>
                <td>".$i. "</td>
               <td>".$row['item']."</td>
               <td>".$row['cat_no']."</td>
               <td>".$to_order."</td>
               <td>".$row['supplier']."</td>      
         </tr>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</table></div>";
?>

<div id="try"></div>
</div>
<div id="mid_col">
<div>Reorder In Process</div>
<div id="reorder_in_process">
<?PHP
include ('db.php');
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM reorder_in_process ORDER BY supplier");
$first_iteration = true;
$current_supplier = null;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // If a new supplier is encountered, close the first table (if its no the first iteration) and add new header + start new table 
    if ($row['supplier'] != $current_supplier) {
        if ($first_iteration == false)
            echo "</table></div>";

        $i = 1;
        $first_iteration = false;
        $current_supplier = $row['supplier'];
        echo "<h4>".$row['supplier']."</h4>";
        echo  "<div><table><tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Cat. No</th>                                            
                    <th>Buy QTY</th>
                    <th>Supplier</th>
       <th>Ordered Time</th>                   
                </tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>
                <td>".$i. "</td>
               <td>".$row['item']."</td>
               <td>".$row['cat_no']."</td>
               <td>".$row['to_order']."</td>
       <td>".$row['supplier']."</td>
               <td>".$row['time']."</td>      
         </tr>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</table></div>";
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Then I have another page: (purchaser_confirm_purchase.php)

```html
<?php
include ('db.php');
$q = strval($_GET['q']);

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE qty_left<=qty_min AND supplier='$q'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
$item = $row2['item'];
$cat_no = $row2['cat_no'];
$qty_max = $row2['qty_max'];
$qty_left = $row2['qty_left'];
$to_order = $row2['qty_max']-$row2['qty_left'];

$qql = "INSERT INTO reorder_in_process VALUES (NULL, '$item', '$to_order', '$cat_no', '$q', now())";
$result_qql = mysqli_query($con,$qql);

}

//-----------------Update reorder_in_process to the PHP page if any new insert.--------------------//

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM reorder_in_process ORDER BY supplier");
$first_iteration = true;
$current_supplier = null;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // If a new supplier is encountered, close the first table (if its no the first iteration) and add new header + start new table 
    if ($row['supplier'] != $current_supplier) {
        if ($first_iteration == false)
            echo "</table></div>";

        $i = 1;
        $first_iteration = false;
        $current_supplier = $row['supplier'];
        echo "<h4>".$row['supplier']."</h4>";
        echo  "<div><table><tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Cat. No</th>                                            
                    <th>Buy QTY</th>
                    <th>Supplier</th>
       <th>Ordered Time</th>                   
                </tr>";
    }

    echo "<tr>
                <td>".$i. "</td>
               <td>".$row['item']."</td>
               <td>".$row['cat_no']."</td>
               <td>".$row['to_order']."</td>
               <td>".$row['supplier']."</td>
       <td>".$row['time']."</td>      
         </tr>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</table></div>";
?>
```

The (purchaser.php) page will output results below:

```
Items Need Reorder                                     Reorder In Process

ACOMP     <Button"Reorder Now">

No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier
1   Orange  1001        42  ACOMP

BCOMP     <Button"Reorder Now">

No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier
1   Apple   1002        16  BCOMP

CCOMP     <Button"Reorder Now">

No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier
1   Durian  1004        91  CCOMP
```

Now if I click the "Reorder Button", it outputs:

```
Items Need Reorder                                 Reorder In Process

ACOMP     <Button"Reorder Now">             ACOMP

No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier        No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier    Ordered Time
1   Orange  1001        42  ACOMP           1   Orange  1001        42  ACOMP   2017-06-09 23:06:42

BCOMP     <Button"Reorder Now">

No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier
1   Apple   1002        16  BCOMP

CCOMP     <Button"Reorder Now">

No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier
1   Durian  1004        91  CCOMP
```

But What I want is this after click:

```
Items Need Reorder                                 Reorder In Process

BCOMP     <Button"Reorder Now">             ACOMP

No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier        No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier    Ordered Time
1   Apple   1002        16  BCOMP           1   Orange  1001        42  ACOMP   2017-06-09 23:06:42


CCOMP     <Button"Reorder Now">

No  Item    Cat. No Buy QTY Supplier
1   Durian  1004        91  CCOMP
```

And it stays tat way even after page reload/refresh.

Pls help. Thanks.

Comment: You don't show any code for the actual process, so you probably won't get much help. But notice that every row has an ID. So use that ID to insert into B, then delete from A.

Comment: My code is quite long ... actually tis just just rough assumption. Any way i will try upload later.

Comment: Hi, I put up the whole code oredi, pls read and give advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Load first table in UI with:

```
Select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

Even after refresh, it will retain correct values in both tables.

If table2 populated with page load, then need not be worried about rendering/hiding.

However, if you are doing it via AJAX, as you rightly said.. you can delete DOM elements via rowid or class which is different from other rows. Eventually the same values has to be created with DOM elements in second table.

Comment: Hi, I put up the whole code oredi, pls read and give more specific advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I found solution myself:

```
"SELECT * FROM inventory  
          WHERE qty_left<=qty_min 
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT cat_no FROM reorder_in_process WHERE cat_no=inventory.cat_no)
          ORDER BY supplier ASC, item ASC");
```

Comment: "Not Exists" not but left join with id is null.. which is more professional. which is what i sent.

Comment: I tried ur suggestion as below:                                                           
    "SELECT * FROM inventory LEFT JOIN reorder_in_process ON inventory.id=reorder_in_process.id 
     WHERE qty_left<=qty_min AND reorder_in_process.id IS NULL 
          ORDER BY supplier ASC, item ASC"); but it won't work. Any mistake with my SQL?

Comment: Very simple, if you are using cat_no as a join in your query, then its same in the my query as well. :) try this: SELECT * FROM inventory LEFT JOIN reorder_in_process ON inventory.cat_no=reorder_in_process.cat_no WHERE qty_left<=qty_min AND reorder_in_process.cat_no IS NULL ORDER BY supplier ASC, item ASC");